# Why the server side validation is not working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is my Movies controller.....

```
public class MoviesController : Controller
{
    MoviesEntities db = new MoviesEntities();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var movies = from m in db.Films
                     where m.ReleaseDate > new DateTime(1989, 12, 20)
                     select m;
        return View(movies.ToList());
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Film newFilm)
    {
        ..some code for adding new movie in the database
    }
}
```

and created Movie class in the model

```
namespace Movies.Models
{

    [MetadataType(typeof(MovieMetadata))]
    public partial class Movie
    {
        class MovieMetadata
        {
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
            public string Title { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
            [Range(5, 100, ErrorMessage = "Movies cost between $5 and $100.")]
            public decimal Price { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

This should give me proper validations.. but the range is not working..
also... they are getting added into database

Comment: The POST method you have shown has a model which is typeof `Film` but the model you have shown is typeof `Movie`

Comment: Use ModelState.IsValid in controller or enable jquery validation

Comment: As @StephenMuecke mentioned, you are showing Movie class, but your POST method receives object of type Film. Please edit your question to explain.

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Film newFilm)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
    ..some code for adding new movie in the database
   }
}
```

Do this. And with regard to the comment of Aman who is saying or JQuery validation. Clientside validation cannot be a replacement for serverside validation. So always use the ModelState validation next to clientside.

Comment: I told for server side use ModelState.IsValid and for client side use jquery validation for the given problem. I gave a hint but not detailed explanation. A good developer can work on this hint instead i think, but unfortunately you didn't understand what i said.

Comment: I understood what you said. I just wanted to make clear to P33K that validation is not client OR serverside.